# Binding IObservableMap to an ItemsControl (e.g. ListView)

Tags: uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I'm having trouble binding an IObservableMap to a ListView with C++/WinRT. My MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind TestCollection}">
</ListView>
```

where `TestCollection` is a method with the signature `winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableMap<hstring, hstring> TestCollection()`.

However, when running the app it crashes in the XAML setup code when setting the `ItemsSource` property to `TestCollection` with `HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)`, which doesn't really tell me much except that it doesn't like the map as a parameter.

I've consulted the docs on this matter and raised an issue with MS docs [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2077) because they are contradictory. To summarize:

The ItemsSource property docs say:

```
The ItemsSource property value must implement one of these interfaces:
IIterable<IInspectable>
IBindableIterable
```

first of which IObservableMap actually implements according to C++/WinRT headers while the C++/WinRT docs say:

```
If you want to bind a XAML items control to your collection, then you can. 
But be aware that to correctly set the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property, you need to set it to a value of type IVector of IInspectable (or of an interoperability type such as IBindableObservableVector).
```

When replacing IObservableMap with IObservableVector everything works as expected.
I've also tried to do the equivalent thing in C# with a (non-observable) Dictionary and it worked just fine, which left me kinda puzzled. How does the CLR accomplish that? Is it converting the Dictionary to an IVector somewhere? It does not work with an IMap in C++, so there must be some sort of conversion going on, right?

**Edit:** after lots of wasted time and assembly-level debugging into `Windows.UI.Xaml.dll`, I've found out following things:

- The ItemsSource method's implementation does a `QueryInterface` for `IIterable<IInspectable>`
- Parameterized interfaces' IIDs are [generated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system#parameterized-types) based on the inserted type parameter
- Even if you implement `IIterable<IKeyValuePair<K,V>>` which is an `IInspectable` that doesn't mean you implement `IIterable<IInspectable>`
- My head hurts

Is there a way to make this work at all?
I've thought about making a custom collection, but that'd mean I need to implement both `IIterable<IKeyValuePair<K,V>>` and `IIterable<IInspectable>` which I've tried for a moment, but that confused the compiler due to having two `First()` methods and it not knowing which one to pick and me not knowing what to do.
Again, how does the CLR solve this?

Comment: When I used IObservableMap or IMap to bind with itemsource, received the same issue. From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/previous-versions/windows/apps/br230301(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#passing-windows-runtime-types-to-managed-code), if implement IDictionary in c#, it'll show up as implementing IMap in C++/WinRT. So it should work, but I'm also confused with this strange behavior, I will continue to check it.

Comment: Have you considered filing an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues) at C++/WinRT's GitHub repository? The team maintaining it is generally quick to respond, and usually provides very helpful feedback.

Comment: Huh, good idea. I forgot that they got one now after archiving the old one.  
I'll try it.

Comment: Why do you want to bind a dictionary to a control used for displaying lists in the first place?
I'm sure your view model could be restructured to not need that.

Comment: Well, of course. I already did that to unblock other work, but I'm still interested why this works in C# and not in C++.

The initial reason was using the Windows.Devices.Enumeration API; there's an Updated event and I need to retrieve the matching DeviceInformation object to update it. It's faster to do that with a map instead of searching through a vector when you have a lot of devices.

Comment: Incidentally, I ran into the exact same problem, right around the same time. I intended to implement a debug interface that lists the application's local settings as returned by `ApplicationData::Current().LocalSettings().Values()`. That returns an [IPropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ipropertyset) that should be usable as-is, but isn't.

Comment: Possibly related, I found a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/2c98bf4402ca36e6ab1544284ff5a56575541d3b/XamlControlsGallery/CollectionsInterop.cs#L13) in the XAML Controls Gallery code, that seems to indicate, that the XAML compiler has intrinsic knowledge of collection types, and how they project to .NET types. Maybe that knowledge is missing when targeting a native projection, like C++/WinRT.

Comment: Alright, so there's been a discussion over at the WinUI and cppwinrt repos over this:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1612,
https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/418.
  
Kenny Kerr provided a map that implements `IIterable<IInspectable>` and works fine when binding as ItemsSource. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Dictionary and it worked just fine, which left me kinda puzzled. How does the CLR accomplish that?

In C# `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` [implements](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#L268) `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`

For C++/CX there is [Platform::Collections::Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-collections-map-class?view=vs-2019) this collection also implements all necessary interfaces.

And for C++/WinRT there is [winrt::observable_map_base struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/observable-map-base). That also implements all necessary interfaces.

Sample implementation from docs:

```cpp
...
#include <iostream>
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
...
struct MyObservableMap :
    implements<MyObservableMap, IObservableMap<winrt::hstring, int>, IMap<winrt::hstring, int>, IMapView<winrt::hstring, int>, IIterable<IKeyValuePair<winrt::hstring, int>>>,
    winrt::observable_map_base<MyObservableMap, winrt::hstring, int>
{
    auto& get_container() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

    auto& get_container() noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    std::map<winrt::hstring, int> m_values{
        { L"AliceBlue", 0xfff0f8ff }, { L"AntiqueWhite", 0xfffaebd7 }
    };
};
```

```cpp
IObservableMap<winrt::hstring, int> map{ winrt::make<MyObservableMap>() };

for (auto const& el : map)
{
    std::wcout << el.Key().c_str() << L", " << std::hex << el.Value() << std::endl;
}

IIterator<IKeyValuePair<winrt::hstring, int>> it{ map.First() };
while (it.HasCurrent())
{
    std::wcout << it.Current().Key().c_str() << L", " << std::hex << it.Current().Value() << std::endl;
    it.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: There is no `Platform::Collections::Map` in C++/WinRT.

Comment: True. But there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/observable-map-base

Comment: Still, this is merely suggesting to use a workaround the OP is well aware of already, and doesn't answer the question, why something that should work doesn't, when using C++/WinRT.

Comment: Also, the problem is that it does *not* implement all necessary interfaces (in C++/WinRT, though I didn't check CX as that's not an acceptable workaround in my case); `IIterable<IInspectable>` is missing. See my comment above with GitHub links for Kenny Kerr's fix.